# Get music taste from facebook users without access token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently working on an app that gathers all people in a facebook event and returns all the peoples music taste. I have managed to return all the id's of the people in a facebook event. I am struggling however to return the music taste of all those people because I believe it requires an access token.

However when viewing random peoples profiles on facebook you can still see there music taste/likes hence why would I need an access token? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get any data of the users without authorization. It does not mean you can grab it with the API if stuff is public on facebook.com.

The only way to get the music of the user is by authorizing him with the `user_likes` permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/music

Edit: I just realized that it may not be possible at all, because in the attendees list you get the global ID of users. If you let users authorize an App, you only get an "App Scoped ID" and you can´t match the App Scoped ID with the global one. Just comparing the name may not be good enough.

TL;DR: Imho it´s not possible.

Comment: So I can grab it when it's public on facebook?

Comment: no, you can´t. you still need authorization and specific permissions. else it would be easy to scrape things, but you are not allowed to scrape public stuff - the user always has to authorize it and know about it.

Comment: So any idea how I could create the app I want to make since getting the authorization of every users seems a little tedious? (And if the data is public I believe it is ethical)

Comment: the main point of my answer is that you can´t create that app ;)

Comment: good luck with your ex-facebook-account. you may want to read the scraping terms: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php - we don´t talk about illegal stuff on stackoverflow, we are honest developers ;)

Comment: Who said anything about scraping? My idea was actually to develop a new type of facebook event where every user gives consent - such a mission though

Comment: lol...well, that would work. i just doubt that all users would authorize an app just for an event. and then there´s the problem with app scoped ids...i will add some information about that in my answer.